# jquery: select and unselect items of listbox

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html

I have 2 listboxes (select, in HTML) in a ASP.NET page. I want that when one item of list1 is selected, the selected item in list2 is unselected, and viceversa.

The 2 selects are mutually exclusive.

How can I do?

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function() {
    var list1 = $("#listbox1");
    var list2 = $("#listbox2");

    list1.change(function() {
        $("option", list2).attr('selected', false);
    });

    list2.change(function() {
        $("option", list1).attr('selected', false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#listbox1").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != "")
            $("#listbox2 option:selected").attr("selected", "");
    });
    $("#listbox2").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != "")
            $("#listbox1 option:selected").attr("selected", "");
    });
});
```

Comment: maybe you could try removeAttr("selected")

Answer (score 0):

I think Aaron's answer would work cross-browser, but in cases like this radio boxes should be used instead of check boxes...

Radio boxes were designed specifically for situations like these...