# Validating between 2 drop down menus so only one can be selected php

Tags: php, mysql, validation, drop-down-menu

I have a script below which the user logs a php form.

There is a section with 2 drop down menus next to each other, 'npc_battery_n_code' and 'npc_battery_other_code'.

What I am trying to do is to make it so one of these drop down menus has to have an option selected for the form to be submitted, but not both or none.

So for example, if an option gets selected in 'npc_battery_n_code' and then the user selects another option in 'npc_battery_other_code', then the value of the 'npc_battery_n_code' will revert to the 'None' option.

Any suggestions welcome

```
     <?php //logsale.php
     require_once ('./includes/config.inc.php');
     $page_title = 'Log a sale';
     include ('./includes/header.html');

     if (!isset($_SESSION['sp_user_id'])) {

     $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
     . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
     // Check for a trailing slash.
     if ((substr($url, -1) == '/') OR (substr($url, -1) == '\\') ) {
     $url = substr ($url, 0, -1); // Chop off the slash.
     }
     $url .= '/login.php'; 

     ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
     header("Location: $url"); 
     exit(); // Quit the script.
     }
     $users = $_SESSION['sp_user_id'];
     ?>

     <h1>Heading</h1>

     <?php

     if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {// Handle the form.

     require_once ('mydatabase.php');

     if (!empty($_POST['npc_quantity'])) {
     $quantity = escape_data($_POST ['npc_quantity']);
     } else {
     $quantity = FALSE;
     echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the Quantity</font></p>';
     }  

     if (!empty($_POST['npc_customer_name'])) {
     $customer = escape_data($_POST ['npc_customer_name']);
     } else {
     $customer = FALSE;
     echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the Customer Name</font></p>';
     }  

     if (!empty($_POST['npc_registration_no'])) {
     $rego = escape_data($_POST ['npc_registration_no']);
     } else {
     $rego = FALSE;
     echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the Customer Rego Number</font></p>';
     }  

     if (!empty($_POST['npc_suo_no'])) {
     $suo = escape_data($_POST ['npc_suo_no']);
     } else {
     $suo = FALSE;
     echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the SUO Number</font></p>';
     }  

     if (!empty($_POST['npc_amb_club_no'])) {
     $repair_order = escape_data($_POST ['npc_amb_club_no']);
     } else {
     $repair_order = FALSE;
     echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the A-Club number</font></p>';
     }  

     if (!empty($_POST['npc_repair_order'])) {
     $amb_club = escape_data($_POST ['npc_repair_order']);
     } else {
     $amb_club = FALSE;
     echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the Repair Order</font></p>';
     }  

     if (!empty($_POST['npc_invoice_no'])) {
     $inv = escape_data($_POST ['npc_invoice_no']);
     } else {
     $inv = FALSE;
     echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the Invoice Number </font></p>';
     }  

     if (!empty($_POST['npc_entry_userdate'])) {
     $inv_date = escape_data($_POST ['npc_entry_userdate']);
     } else {
     $inv_date = FALSE;
     echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the Invoice Date</font></p>';
     }

     if ($quantity && $customer && $rego && $suo && $repair_order && $amb_club && $inv && $inv_date)  {

     $uid = @mysql_insert_id(); //Get the url ID.
     $query = "INSERT INTO npc_sales_list 
     (npc_item_id , sp_user_id, npc_battery_n_code, npc_battery_other_code, npc_quantity, 
     npc_customer_name, npc_registration_no, npc_suo_no, npc_amb_club_no, npc_repair_order,
     npc_entry_userdate, npc_usertype, npc_points, npc_bonus_points, npc_entry_date)
     VALUES
     ('$uid', '$users', '$_POST[npc_battery_n_code]', '$_POST[npc_battery_other_code]', '$quantity',
     $customer , $rego, $suo, $amb_club , $repair_order, 
     $inv , 'NPC', '5' , '0' , NOW())";
     $result = mysql_query ($query) or trigger_error
     ("Query: $query\n<br />MySQL Error: " .mysql_error());

     if ($result = @mysql_query($query)) {

     //Finish the page.
     echo '<p>The sale with invoice number: <strong>' . $inv . '</strong>       <br />
     is now registered into the system.</p>
     <p>If you would like to log in further sales, please <a href="logsale.php">click here</a></p>
     <p>If you would like to view your sales log, please <a href="viewsales.php">click here</a></p>
     ';
     include ('./includes/footer.html'); // Include the HTML footer.
     exit();

     } else { // If it did not run OK.
     echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">You could not be
     registered due to a system error. We apologize for any
     inconvenience.</font></p>';
     }

     } 

     } else { // If one of the data tests failed.
     echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">Please check all manatory fields are complete and try again.
     </font></p>';
     }

     mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.

     ?>                         


     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="logsale.php" method="post">


     <table width="520" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2">

     <tr>
     <td width="184"><div align="right">NPC Vehicle<span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
     <td width="323"><select  name="npc_battery_n_code" id="npc_battery_n_code">
     <option value="None" 
     <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_n_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_n_code'] == 'None') 
     {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>None
     </option>
     <option value="55D23L" 
     <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_n_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_n_code'] == '55D23L') 
     {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>55D23L
     </option>
     <option value="55D23R" 
     <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_n_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_n_code'] == '55D23R') 
     {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>55D23R
     </option>                                
     <option value="75D23R" 
     <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_n_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_n_code'] == '75D23R') 
     {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>75D23R
     </option>
     </select></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td width="184"><div align="right">Other <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
     <td width="323">
     <select  name="npc_battery_other_code" id="npc_battery_other_code">
     <option value="50D20L" 
     <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_other_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_other_code'] == '50D20L') 
     {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>50D20L
     </option>
     <option value="50D20R" 
     <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_other_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_other_code'] == '50D20R') 
     {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>50D20R
     </option>
     <option value="55D23LMF" 
     <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_other_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_other_code'] == '55D23LMF') 
     {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>55D23LMF
     </option>
     <option value="55D23RMF" 
     <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_other_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_other_code'] == '55D23RMF') 
     {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>55D23RMF
     </option>
     </select></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td><div align="right">Quantity <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="npc_quantity" size="10" maxlength="10" 
     value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_quantity'])) echo $_POST['npc_quantity']; ?>" /></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td><div align="right">Customer name<span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
     <td><input type="text"  name="npc_customer_name" size="30" maxlength="30" 
     value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_customer_name'])) echo $_POST['npc_customer_name']; ?>" /></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td><div align="right">Rego number <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="npc_registration_no" size="10" maxlength="7" 
     value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_registration_no'])) echo $_POST['npc_registration_no']; ?>" /></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td><div align="right">SUO No.<span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="npc_suo_no" size="10" maxlength="7" 
     value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_suo_no'])) echo $_POST['npc_suo_no']; ?>"/></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td><div align="right">A-Club ID<span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="npc_amb_club_no" size="15" maxlength="7" 
     value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_amb_club_no'])) echo $_POST['npc_amb_club_no']; ?>"/></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td><div align="right">Repair Order <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="npc_repair_order" size="15" maxlength="12" 
     value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_repair_order'])) echo $_POST['npc_repair_order']; ?>" /></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td><div align="right">Invoice No. <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
     <td><input size="10" name="npc_invoice_no" 
     value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_invoice_no'])) echo $_POST['npc_invoice_no']; ?>" /></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td><div align="right">Invoice Date <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
     <td><input size="12" name="npc_entry_userdate" maxlength="10" 
     value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_entry_userdate'])) echo $_POST['npc_entry_userdate']; ?>"/>  </td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
     &nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     </form>

     <p>Footer</p>


     <?php
     include ('./includes/footer.html');
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jquery: select and unselect items of listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582361/jquery-select-and-unselect-items-of-listbox) is what you are looking for.

How you want your script to work cannot be achieved with PHP or Mysql. You can only work with the data when the website is loaded. If you want to edit the data without refreshing the page you need to use JavaScript, or more advanced jQuery.

Comment: Thanks #Leon Kramer, this was what I was after!